# echo something inside a shortcode

Tags: php, woocommerce-offtopic, shortcode

I'm a frontender, so i'm not so used to work with php. But I need to solve something. I'm adding a shortcode within the single-product template, and inside this shortcode, I need to echo the slug from the product.

I've tried multiple things, but I cant get it to work.

```
<?php 
    global $post;
    $post_slug = $post->post_name;
    echo $post_slug;
    echo do_shortcode('[sc name=" I NEED TO ECHO THE POST SLUG HERE "]');
?>
```

Maybe some of you, could help me out :)

Best regards,
Michael

Comment: Hello Michael - Welcome to the WordPress Development community! While your question is regarding an issue within the context of WordPress, it's not actually a question about working with WordPress - rather it's a question about generic PHP syntax. As such, it might be considered [off-topic](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) for our stack. [webmasters.se] or [so] might be a more appropriate place to ask.

Answer (score 2):

There are a few to do this:

#### Using [double quotes](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.syntax.double)

Don't forget to escape the double quotes inside the string.

```php
global $post;
echo do_shortcode("[sc name=\"$post->post_name\"]");
```

#### Using [sigle quotes](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.syntax.single)

```php
global $post;
echo do_shortcode("[sc name='$post->post_name']");
```

#### Using [sprintf](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.sprintf.php)

```php
global $post;
echo do_shortcode(
  sprintf('[sc name="%s"]', $post->post_name)
);
```

#### Using [wp_sprintf](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_sprintf/)

```php
global $post;
echo do_shortcode(
  wp_sprintf('[sc name="%s"]', $post->post_name)
);
```

#### Using [heredoc](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.syntax.heredoc)

```php
do_shortcode(
    <<< EOF
[add_to_cart_url id="$post->post_name"]
EOF
);
```

Comment: Awesome! It worked! :D Thank you so much :)

Comment: Glad to help! :)